# Windows Subsystem for LinuxでUbuntu 16.04を使用していますがSony Spresenseが使用できません

Tags: spresense

Windows Subsystem for LinuxでUbuntu 16.04を使用していますがSony Spresenseが使用できません

1. Windows PowerShellで、Windows Subsystem for Linuxを有効にします
2. Microsoft StoreからUbuntu16.04を入手し、インストールします
3. SonyのSPRESENSEをUSB経由で接続しようとしますが、デバイスが見えません

なお、Windows側ではCOM3で接続されていることは、デバイスマネージャで確認済

Ubuntu側では、`dmesg | grep "cp21.*attached"`を実行しても、何も出てきませんし、
`dev/ttyS3`で見えると思いましたが、これも見えません

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: この記事 [SpresenseをWindows10(WSL)で開発する](https://qiita.com/FlyingYacht/items/0f49ed82b4912381ffe7) だと、Ubuntu の後にシリアル変換ドライバとか Spresense SDK をインストール＆環境構築しているようです。

Comment: 少し情報不足でした
https://developer.sony.com/ja/develop/spresense/developer-tools/get-started-using-nuttx/set-up-the-nuttx-environment
の手順に従って、USBに接続したのですが、Windows COM3には見えますが、Ubuntu側では見えません

Comment: SONYのページはUbuntu単独環境での説明と思われます。紹介したWSLでの記事の方法を試してみてはどうでしょう？　更に両方の環境からも違いがあるのなら、それに応じた読み替えが必要になるでしょう。

Comment: WSLでやる上で、ご提示いただいたサイトは確認していて、ドライバの入れ替えなんかもやっているんですが、うまくいかないんです。

Comment: そうですか、その場合は手順の何処までやってどういう状況で進めないでいるかについて質問に追記して、サポート担当の人が答えてくれるのを待つか、使っていないPCを転用するか安いPCを購入してUbuntu単独環境を構築して試してみるといった対処が考えられます。

Comment: 別PCを準備する案は、当初から考えていないので、（なのでWSLを使っているので）、一旦ゼロリセットして、インストールから始めてみます

Comment: もしかしたら、Arduino IDEでの開発にある [1.2. 事前準備](https://developer.sony.com/ja/develop/spresense/developer-tools/get-started-using-arduino-ide/set-up-the-arduino-ide#_%E4%BA%8B%E5%89%8D%E6%BA%96%E5%82%99) の「Windows 10 環境では、上記 URL より v10.1.3 をダウンロードしてお使いください。」が関係しているかもしれませんね。

Comment: ありがとうございます。このドライバも、すでに入れ替えています。ネットに出ていることは、基本、全部やってます。申し訳ありません

Comment: もう一つの大前提である、SpresenseSDKではなく、ArduinoIDE環境ではどうでしょう？　そちらでもダメならハード系(ボード/ファーム/USBケーブル等)の可能性も考えられます。

Comment: WindowsではCOM3にある（デバイスマネージャで確認済）ので、ハード系が原因である可能性は薄いです。Windows上に開発環境があれば、一番よいのですが

Comment: ArduinoIDEはWindows上での開発環境のように見えるのですが、SpresenseSDKにこだわりがあるのなら、試行錯誤するしか無いですね。

Comment: Spresenseの性能をちゃんと引き出したいため、SpresenseSDKにこだわってます

Answer (score 1):

自分も同じWSL(Ubuntu16.04)環境ですが問題無く使えています。
こんな感じで先頭に `sudo` を付けたら解決しないでしょうか？

```
$ sudo tools/flash.sh -c /dev/ttyS3 nuttx.spk
$ sudo minicom -D /dev/ttyS3 -b 115200 -s
```

あと、Windows10は比較的新しいバージョンじゃないといけないみたいです。

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。しかしながら、Cannot open port : /dev/ttys3やcannot open /dev/ttys3となります

Comment: OSは常に最新化しており、パッチも全部あてています

Comment: WSL環境の問題ですかね。。ls /dev と入力したときに`/dev/ttyS3`は表示されるのか？WindowsでTeraterm等の環境だとCOM3に接続できるのか？ちょっとよく分からないですね。`/dev/ttyS3`とSは大文字にしてますよね(上のコメントが小文字なので念の為)

Comment: Windows+ArudinoIDEでは、正しく動作していることを確認しました。ハードの問題ではないようです

Comment: ls /devで/dev/ttyS3は出ます。もちろんS3のSは大文字です。Windows+ArudinoIDEではうまくいったのでSpresenseSDKを最初からやり直してみましたが、はやり同じ現象です。

Answer (score 0):

私はビルドのみWSLで行い、書き込みはWindowsのコマンドラインから行っています。
手順はこちらを参考にしました。
https://qiita.com/FlyingYacht/items/0f49ed82b4912381ffe7

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。上記URLの手順で試しておりますが./configureでエラーになります。/mnt/C/(以降省略）でエラーおよびCコンパイラが見つからないエラーです

Comment: 元々自分がやっていた手順で、ビルドまでをWSL+Ubuntsuで行って、そのファイルをWindows経由で書き込んだらできました。上記URLは、Windowsから書き込む手順だけ参考にしました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

少し本筋ではない回答になりますが、私のWSL環境ではUbuntu 18.04でうまく動いています。
シリアルポートは私の環境ではCOM6なので/dev/ttyS6になり、書き込みもsudoを付加することで問題なくできています。
公式には16.04が推奨のようですが、18.04にしてみるのも一案です。